# unsigned bit field holding negative value

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I'd like to work with 12 bits unsigned integer. Since I am working with array, it is of interest for me to have overflowing value, e.g., `0 - 1 = 4095`.

I tried the following but I don't obtain the expected behaviour:

```
struct bit_field
{
    unsigned int x: 12; // 12 bits
};

bit_field ii, jj, kk;
ii.x = 4096;
jj.x = 1;
kk.x = 0;
cout << ii.x;
cout << kk.x - jj.x;
```

Output:

```
>> 0   // ov as expected
>> -1  // expected 4095
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? I'm seeing an output of `4294967295` with msvc (https://godbolt.org/z/G1Kd9f11f) and `-1` with clang (https://godbolt.org/z/98jYjbx9h).

Comment: I think you're running into the usual arithmetic conversions in the subtraction.

Comment: Change to `cout << ((kk.x - jj.x) & 4095);` to get the expected 4095.

Comment: Maybe this is what you wanted: https://godbolt.org/z/anK4M6rsK

Answer (score 1):

This is how C/C++ is expected to work; you don't get arbitarily sized integers. your storage width declaration within the struct doesn't change that: the type your operators see is **still** `unsigned int`. It's just that you say "when I store  this, it's 12 bits".

Because `kk.x` and `kk.x` are unsigned integers, their subtraction works just as defined for these: their subtraction is promoting values to signed integers.

Note that you're writing C++, so you can perfectly well write your own class that implements the mathematical operations you want and has cast operators for integer types.

Comment: Is there a compiler bug here or is it unspecified in the standard if this gets promoted to an `int`? msvc and clang give different results.

Comment: I am afraid a custom class would be less efficient. My loop operation is timed.

Comment: @mooder sorry, your CPU simply doesn't have a 12 bit integer mode, you will *have* to program that. So, there's no difference between you, every time you want to act as if these numbers were 12 bit integers, manually implement 12 bit integer subtraction, or use a type with an overloaded `-` operator that does that. C++ compilers will inline that. So, **no**, a custom class will not be less efficient.

Comment: the thing probably is that you *think* you need 12 bit integer arithmetic, whereas you could just as well implement the same using a larger integer type, and do the wrapping/conversion/storing to 12 bit in a separate step

Comment: @BillLynch As far as I can read from the standard Clang does the right thing. "A prvalue for an integral bit-field (9.2.4) can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the bit-field; otherwise, it can be converted to `unsigned int` if `unsigned int` can represent all the values of the bit-field."

Comment: Your answer is misleading in one way - just because the bitfields are unsigned doesn't mean they'll get promoted to unsigned int. That's key to understanding the observed result.

Comment: @MarkRansom true, hopefully fixed that.

Comment: Not quite. The promotion rules will go to int first, and only unsigned int if the values won't fit. Since the unsigned 12 bit range of 0-4095 fits fine in an int, that's what they get promoted to.